# XAMPP - Alias 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost, alias

Currently, I have XAMPP setup to where typing 127.0.0.1 in the browser redirects me to the home page found within htdocs.

I would like to be able to type "devtest" and have that be an alias for 127.0.0.1.

What I have tried so far is modifying: `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd.vhosts.conf` where I added an entry that looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace\MyProject
    ServerName devtest
    ErrorLog C:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace\MyProject\MyProject-error_log
    CustomLog C:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace\MyProject\MyProject-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there another step I'm missing?

Comment: Perhaps this was implied by the question, but the name "devtest" does actually resolve to an IP address of your server right?

Comment: Did you edit the `hosts` file? If it worked please accept the answer; asking questions here on SO requires accepting answers to keep asking questions. ;-)

Comment: @John sorry, yes your answer is the right answer and easiest way to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `hosts` file in Notepad:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Add the line:

```
127.0.0.1 devtest
```

Navigate to: http://devtest

Answer (score 1):

Use this, and make sure you enable using vhosts config file in apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace\MyProject"
    ServerName devtest.local
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace\MyProject">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Just double checking - is the control for enabling vhosts config file in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`? And if so, is it this line (in `http-vhosts.conf`): `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`?